# MVC; Error message on my Controller HTTPOST action edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am working to add a edit function to my MVC 3 EF model first project, There is a list and a user is suppose to be able to edit a row of `Questions`.

My entities are `Questions`, `CoreVaue` and SubjectType, `CoreValue` and `SubjectType` have many to many relationship to `Question`.

Note: Dont make the name of CreateViewModel confuse you, I use it on Create and Delete views. :)

This is my GET action inside my `Controller`:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Question q = Arep.GetQuestionById(id);
    CreateViewModel model = new CreateViewModel();
    List<SubjectType> subjectypes = Arep.getallS();
    List<CoreValue> corevalues = Arep.getallC();
    model.SubjectTypes = new SelectList(subjectypes, "SID", "Sname");
    model.CoreValues = new SelectList(corevalues, "CID", "Cname");

    return View(model);
}
```

This is my methods inside my `AdminRepository`:

```
   public Question GetQuestionById(int id)
    {
    return db.Question.SingleOrDefault(m => m.QID == id);
    }

   public void changequestion(Question question)
    {  
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(question, EntityState.Modified); 
    }

    public List<SubjectType> getallS()
    {
        var Allsubjectypes = from SID in db.SubjectType
                             select SID;
        return Allsubjectypes.ToList();
    }

    public List<CoreValue> getallC()
    {
        var AllCorevalues = from CID in db.CoreValue
                            select CID;
        return AllCorevalues.ToList();
    }
```

This is my POST action inside my `Controller`:

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult EditConfirmed(CreateViewModel model)
{
    Question question = new Question();
    //question.QID = id;//test
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Arep.changequestion(question);
        Arep.save();
        return RedirectToAction("Edit");
    }
    var CoreValueID = int.Parse(model.Cname);
    var SubjectTypeID = int.Parse(model.Sname);
    var getallC = Arep.getbycid(CoreValueID);
    var getallS = Arep.getbysid(SubjectTypeID);



     return View(model);
}
```

And this is my CreateViwModel:

```
public string QuestionText { get; set; }
public string Cname { get; set; }
public string Sname { get; set; }

public SelectList SubjectTypes { get; set; }
public SelectList CoreValues { get; set; }
```

This is basicly my code for editing and I get this eror when I try to change values and submit it:

```
Current Object State Manager contains no Object Stat Entry that references an object of type NKI3.Models.Question.
```

I have no clue what casuses this error? :S

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EditConfirmed, I think you want to get an existing question, not create a new question. The new question is not tracked by ObjectContext.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult EditConfirmed(CreateViewModel model)
{
    Question question = new Question(); // I think you want to get a existing question here
    //question.QID = id;//test
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Arep.changequestion(question);
        Arep.save();
        return RedirectToAction("Edit");
    }
    var CoreValueID = int.Parse(model.Cname);
    var SubjectTypeID = int.Parse(model.Sname);
    var getallC = Arep.getbycid(CoreValueID);
    var getallS = Arep.getbysid(SubjectTypeID);



     return View(model);
}
```